# What in the following code could be missing or at fault? There is no difference in size between textstyle and displaystyle

Tags: math-operators

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{slashed}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathabx} % \degree\third

\usepackage{MnSymbol}% \plus

% Latex standard:      \times

\newcommand{\boto}{\ensuremath{{\declareslashed{\mathop}{\degree}{-.01}{.4}{\bot}\slashed{\bot}}}}

\newcommand{\oog}{\ensuremath{{\declareslashed{\mathop}{\times}{0}{0}{\plus}\slashed{\plus}}}}

\newcommand{\Letne}[1]{\ensuremath{{\declareslashed{\mathop}{\third}{-.2}{-1.3}{#1}\slashed{#1}}}}

\begin{document}


\[\Letne{\oog}\textstyle\Letne{\oog} \scriptstyle\Letne {\oog}\scriptscriptstyle\Letne{\oog}\]

\[\Letne{\boto}\textstyle\Letne{\boto}\scriptstyle\Letne{\boto}\scriptscriptstyle\Letne{\boto}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think the modified symbols are supposed to change size in `\displaystyle`. You can see the same effect with `\[ x \textstyle x \scriptstyle x \scriptscriptstyle x\]`. For many things `\displaystyle` does not directly influence the size, instead it modifies how sub and superscripts behave.

Comment: Why do you expect a difference? x has the same size in textstyle and displaystyle too.

Comment: There are differences like e.g. `\frac` behave very different. But the font size is the same for the two.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher I expect a difference as this is usual for all math operators in latex; the following code shows that.\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[\sum\textstyle\sum\scriptstyle\sum\scriptscriptstyle\sum\]

\[\prod\textstyle\prod\scriptstyle\prod\scriptscriptstyle\prod\]

\end{document}

Comment: But you are not using \sum in your definition but \plus.

Comment: @ Ulrike fisher et al The problem seems clearer: I had overlooked le fact that there are 2 kinds of operator, those with 4 sizes and those with 3 sizes, the displaystyle and textstyle sizes being the same for those later; the standard operator "\max" (2nd kind) shows that :

\[\max\textstyle\max\scriptstyle\max\scriptscriptstyle\max\] 

The above command of definition is  specific to the  second kind; 

This plain example appears to be confirming that:  \newcommand\angarr{\declareslashed{}{\uparrow}{-.08}{.2}{\rightarrow}\slashed{\rightarrow}}

Answer (score 2):

Based on *font* information, some symbols are able to grow up in size when in `\displaystyle`; it is the case of `\sum`, `\bigcup` and similar “large operators”.

From the TeXbook, bottom of page 443 and top of page 444:

> **13.** If the current item is an Op atom, mark this atom as having limits if it has been marked with `\limits`, or if it has been marked with `\displaylimits` and *C* > *T*. If the nucleus is not a symbol, set δ ← 0 and go to Rule 13a. Otherwise if *C* > *T* and if the nucleus symbol has a successor in its font, move to the successor. (This is where operators like ∑ and ∫ change to a larger size in display styles.)

From the rule it is clear that if an Op atom does not consist of a single symbol or this symbol has no successor (usually a larger version thereof), it will be printed the same in `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, both of which use `\textfont<math family>` for typesetting.

So, even if you declare `\mathop\Delta`, this symbol will not grow, because `\textfont0` (where the symbol is declared to belong) has no successor information for it. To the contrary, we can see in `cmex10.pl` (the human readable version of `cmex10.pl`)

```
(CHARACTER O 120
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARDP R 1.000013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 130)
   )
```

Since `\sum` is defined as `\mathchar"1350`, which means “math operator” (1), “math family 3”, “slot `"50`” (octal `` `120 ``), we see in the font information that it has a successor at slot (octal) `` `130 ``.

If we look at `cmr10.pl` (after checking that `\Delta` is `\mathchar"7001`, that is, “variable family” (7), “math family 0”, “slot "01”, we see instead

```
(CHARACTER O 0
   (CHARWD R 0.625002)
   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
   )
```

No successor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems clearer: I had overlooked le fact that there are 2 kinds of operator, those with 4 sizes and those with 3 sizes, the displaystyle and textstyle sizes being the same for those later; the standard operator "\max" (2nd kind) shows that : [\max\textstyle\max\scriptstyle\max\scriptscriptstyle\max] The above command of definition is specific to the second kind; This plain example appears to be confirming that: \newcommand\angarr{\declareslashed{}{\uparrow}{-.08}{.2}{\rightarrow}\slashed{\rightarrow}}

Comment: This answer is rather confusing I think. there are (typically) three sizes of font loaded: text, script and scriptscript sizes. Some display operators (such as \sum) are available in two sizes _in the same font_  with the appropriate character being used from the font as specified by the font metrics, so similar to the way extended brackets work.

Comment: I only meant to say that the definition I used can only provide operators of the type of \max and \sin for which the display and text sizes
are the same, whereas in order to provide new operators that are available in four sizes, such as \sum, an other command of definition
is needed; I've retrieved such a command from my ''stacks'' and it turns out consistently new symbols of operator that can be used in the
four sizes (it's DeclareRobustCommand); those new symbols do have the four sizes, all different the ones from the others: display, text, script and scriptscript.

Comment: No `\DeclareRobustCommand` is completely unrelated to math sizes.

Comment: @ David Carlisle There must be an important point that I miss and I'll have to wait till my understanding improves; I'd hate to waste your time and I 'll leave it at that for the time being; maybe after I've invested some study time in *The LaTeX Companion* will it be worthwhile for me to get back to this subject. Thanks for trying!